# Lilypond: Accidentals #3 and b2 for Turkish music

Tags: lilypond, music-notation

I'm transcribing some music for [bağlama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba%C4%9Flama), a stringed instrument with frets that can produce notes that are not part of traditional Western music.

I'd like to transcribe some notes using accidentals ♭<sup>2</sup> and ♯<sup>3</sup>. Is there a way to do so in Lilypond?

Comment: Related: [post on SE:Music Theory and Practice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/71114/lilypond-custom-key-signature-for-turkish-folk-music-and-microtonal-accidental)

Answer (score 0):

LilyPond is indeed capable of notating non-Western music and is already set for notating Turkish classical music. Please refer to the two pages below:

http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-non_002dwestern-music

and

http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/turkish-classical-music

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of these pages and they don't concern the type of notation my question is about. I don't transcribe Turkish classical music, btw. It's folk and pop music from about 1930 until today I'm interested in.

Comment: In that case, perhaps it would be useful to add an image to your question showing how those accidetanls look like in the score. LilyPond is quite flexible and it might be possible to implement what you are looking for.

Comment: I'd prefer to have the accidentals look as they do in my post: ♭ or ♯ followed by a superscripted number. It'd be fine if the number was not superscripted. An example can be found at the very bottom of [this page](https://www.arifbalyemez.com/ders-30-bir-goenuele-ask-girince) (even though ♯2 is used there).